# Extjs 3 having problems with time to dateformat

Tags: extjs

I have got this time stamp: 1400000000, which is 05/13/2014. Is there a way to display this in my grid, panel or dialog as a m/d/Y.

```
  config.cm =  new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults:{
        sortable: true
    },
    columns :  [{ 
        {
        header: 'date',
        dataIndex: 'time',
        editable:'false'
    }]
});
```

Is there any way to show epoch time as dateformat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this :

```
config.cm =  new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults:{
        sortable: true
    },
    columns :  [{ 
        {
        header: 'date',
        dataIndex: 'time',
        editable:'false',
        renderer: formatDate
    }]
});

function formatDate(value){
    return value ? value.dateFormat('M d, Y') : '';
}
```

Hopefully that helps you!

Comment: I used a database trigger to convert the timestamps to dateformat
BEGIN
set @@lc_time_names=nl_NL;
update main_table set time_column=
from_unixtime(NEW.start_time, '%d %M %Y')
where model_id=NEW.id;
END